# Cannot create volume from Image3D function in Mathematica

Tags: arrays, image-processing, multidimensional-array, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

I'm getting an error when using Image3D function of mathematica. I am trying to use that function to create a 3D volume from the array imagevar, which contains 10 grayscale binary images.

```
images = FileNames["*.png"];
count = 1;
Do[imagevar[count++] = Import[image], {image, images}]
Image3D[imagevar[]]
```

Whenever I run it, it returns with the following error message:

During evaluation of Image3D::imgarray: The specified argument imagevar[] should be an array of rank 3 or 4 with machine-sized numbers.

Conversely, when I try to do

```
Image3D[FileNames["*.jpg"]]
```

instead, it also gives me the same error.

I have made sure that all of the values of the images are between 0 and 255.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: you should do: `imagevar = Import/@images` (start fresh or `Clear[imagevar]` first.. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Mathematica syntax is seriously wonky.  And you probably shouldn't be using `Do`, or any other looping construct, in the first place.  Let's take some baby steps before we try to walk ...

According to the documentation, and my experience, `Image3D[{img1,img2}]` loads the list of 2D images (the list is `{img1,img2}}`) into a 3D image.  So you could try:

```
images = FileNames["*.png"];
img1 = Import[images[[1]]];
img2 = Import[images[[2]]];
Image3D[{img1,img2}]
```

and see what you get.  If you don't get a 3D image comprising your first two 2D images there's something very odd going on.

*And at this point it's time to go home here, so I'll come back later and see how you got on.  If this works, all you have left to do is to figure out how to build a list of all the 2D images you want to use.*

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out the problem. I'm just using the wrong syntax on my imagevar. It should be just Image3D[imagevar] rather than Image3D[imagevar[]].